# Instant web notification

Tags: php, mysql, real-time, mqtt

Straight to my issue, I have a database which has casino tables; each table has some places, where I can add people and remove them.

All this works fine, but when I open my project on two different browsers, I cant see the updates which I've done from the other one.

So I was thinking for AJAX request on every 5sec or something like this, but I don't like this approach.

Then I started to look for another solution and found this MQTT server, but couldn't find a good example how it works with MySQL. I saw that Mosquito-PHP library, and maybe I can get it works on my server, but I'm confused How to get the status. If someone add a person to a table. How Do I check, there is a change?

I've red that the MQTT use something as infinity loop is it good idea to check in MySQL for changes in this loop?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions; and, sorry for my English, still learning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to divide your complicated task into simpler parts, possibly these could be a guideline:

- for each browser session you should have a last update date
- whenever the browser extracts relevant data, your session's update date should be updated
- you should have a last event date on the server
- you should send ajax request every five seconds to the server, called heartbeat event
- upon each heartbeat, the server should check whether your last update is earlier than the last event and send a response in this vein
- if your ajax request yields the result that your status is not at least as new as the last update, the client-side should send another request for new info